# Command line archive manager / extracter

Tags: command-line, scripts, compression, archive, file-roller

I keep forgetting all the corresponding extract commands for every compression format.

So I was thinking about writing a script that merely maps file extensions to the appropriate extract command. But I guess something like this already exists, I just can't find it.

I would be happy with something like file-roller, but file-roller is a GUI tool.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A couple of suggestions:

### unp

unp (available from software-center) is a small perl module that will decompress a wide variety of archives into the current folder.  Use `unp -s` for the archive formats it supports

By default, it decompresses archives into the current folder.

### file-roller

file-roller itself can be run from the command line. Use `file-roller -h <archive name>` to decompress the archive.

Answer (score 11):

From [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=25166), to put in your .bashrc:

```
extract () {
   if [ -f $1 ] ; then
      case $1 in
         *.tar.bz2)   tar xjf $1      ;;
         *.tar.gz)   tar xzf $1      ;;
         *.bz2)      bunzip2 $1      ;;
         *.rar)      rar x $1      ;;
         *.gz)      gunzip $1      ;;
         *.tar)      tar xf $1      ;;
         *.tbz2)      tar xjf $1      ;;
         *.tgz)      tar xzf $1      ;;
         *.zip)      unzip $1      ;;
         *.Z)      uncompress $1   ;;
         *)         echo "'$1' cannot be extracted via extract()" ;;
      esac
   else
      echo "'$1' is not a valid file"
   fi
}
```

Comment: Add an example of how to use it?

Comment: extract file.zip

Comment: `*.zst)    zstd -d $1    ;;`

Answer (score 6):

What hasn't yet been mentioned is the *swiss-army-knife* of command-line utilities: `atool`; it is available in the repositories: click [atool](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/atool) [image: Install atool] or run `sudo apt-get install atool`.

`atool` is actually a [script](http://www.nongnu.org/atool/) comprising various functions such as aunpack, apack, als, acat, adiff, and arepack. Probably the most common use of the program is to extract archives using the aunpack command. There are quite a few interesting and useful options, but the basic way to extract most archives is just to run, for example,

```
aunpack myarchive.tar
```

The support for tar, 7z, zip, jar, rar, ar, lha and many more archive formats and their variations are documented by entering `man atool` in the terminal or by viewing [the Ubuntu manpage online](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/atool.1.html).

So, the useful thing is that if you have a tar, zip and gz archive in the same folder, all you need to do to extract them all is to run

```
aunpack -e *
```

and all supported archives will be unpacked with their folder structure retained. If the name of the resulting folder already exists, it will not be overwritten, but will be given a unique name like unpack-5645.

Or if you want to choose just one type of archive and unpack them all, instead use

```
aunpack -e *.zip
```

If you need files unpacked directly in a particular directory, with only the sub folder directory structure being retained (if it exits), enter, for example,

```
aunpack -e Scripts11.zip -X /home/mike/Videos
```

If a file with the same name already exists, you will be prompted for an action either to rename or overwrite unless you have specified the force option (`-f`) in the command.

As the manpage notes, aunpack first extracts

> files  to  a  unique
>          (temporary) directory, and then mov[es] its contents back  if  possible.
>          This also prevents local files from being overwritten by mistake.

---

With the other tools, other actions are possible, as mentioned by the [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/atool.1.html):

- *apack* creates archives from the files or folder specifies or stdin
- *als*  lists files within the specifies archive
- *acat* enables one to extract archive files to stdout
- *adiff* enables you to compare the two archives specified
- *arepack* makes it possible to convert one archive format to another by placing the contents of the original archive in a temporary folder and then repacking the new one.

---

There are many more useful options for all of the utilities, but probably the one used the most will be aunpack, as that makes it so easy to extract multiple, different archives. It is great to be able to just issue one command and be able to extract multiple different archive formats without having to use the various commands for tar, zip, etc.

For a very recent article describing how to integrate the atool functions into the custom actions of your filemanager, such as Thunar, see [this online magazine](http://pclosmag.com/html/Issues/201304/page08.html).

Answer (score 3):

There is a tool called `dtrx` -- do the right extraction.

Install it from the Ubuntu repositories and run `dtrx somefile.someext`. The tool will interactively query the user about nested archives (zip of zip files).

dtrx is a sophisticated version of [frabjous's extract](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57981/command-line-archive-manager-extracter/57983#57983).

Answer (score 0):

What kind of formats do you need to deal with?  One way is to write a shell script, which checks the extensions of its argument.  Or, if all you deal with is variations on .tar.*, simply doing `tar -xf` will deal with most of those automatcially.  (I therefore only remember that and `unzip` which suffice for everything I usually come across.)