# How to quickly extract all kinds of archived files from command-line?

Tags: command-line, tar, archive, unzip, jar

Many times I need to extract different kinds of archived files using commad-line. But not all the time I remember the exact command for any type of file archive. So, I have to waste time and search again. How can I avoid this?

Comment: See also `atool`, with which you can extract/pack multiple formats: see the answer I gave for this question: [command-line-archive-manager-extracter](http://askubuntu.com/questions/57981/command-line-archive-manager-extracter/220367#220367). This question is also a duplicate of that one, so they probably should be merged.

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/73359/universal-extractors

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the following shell script (I named it `extract` and I put it in `~/bin`):

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -lt 1 ];then
  echo "Usage: `basename $0` FILES"
  exit 1
fi

# I found the following function at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/168/37944
# which I improved it a little. Many thanks to sydo for this idea.
extract () {
    for arg in $@ ; do
        if [ -f $arg ] ; then
            case $arg in
                *.tar.bz2)  tar xjf $arg      ;;
                *.tar.gz)   tar xzf $arg      ;;
                *.bz2)      bunzip2 $arg      ;;
                *.gz)       gunzip $arg       ;;
                *.tar)      tar xf $arg       ;;
                *.tbz2)     tar xjf $arg      ;;
                *.tgz)      tar xzf $arg      ;;
                *.zip)      unzip $arg        ;;
                *.Z)        uncompress $arg   ;;
                *.rar)      rar x $arg        ;;  # 'rar' must to be installed
                *.jar)      jar -xvf $arg     ;;  # 'jdk' must to be installed
                *)          echo "'$arg' cannot be extracted via extract()" ;;
            esac
        else
            echo "'$arg' is not a valid file"
        fi
    done
}

extract $@
```

Don't forget to make the script executable:

```
chmod +x ~/bin/extract
```

Usage:

```
extract file_1 file_2 ... file_n
```

Comment: Nice one. I find that zip sometimes extracts into the current directory, when I want it it its own subdirectory. Using unzip -d `basename $arg` might help.

Answer (score 16):

The `dtrx` command is your friend on that matter.

It uncompresses any archive file by guessing its type.
It will also make sure the files you uncompress will be put in a new directory ; avoiding messing up the current working dir with tons of files.

### Install

```
sudo aptitude install dtrx
```

### Usage

```
dtrx stuff.zip
```